# Позиционирование элементов в Flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

[image: Объяснение]

[image: Пример макета]

Недавно познакомился с flexbox хотел сверстать макет используя flex'ы  на второй картинке видно что именно я хочу сверстать я создал первый div которому дал свойство display:flex,внутри поместил еще два дива как я знаю они автоматически становятся flex элементами,так вот я все сделал,но остался один банальный вопрос,а лого фотки и т.д(контент) позиционируются так же как и при верстке блоками? Например что бы дать отступ логотипу можно использовать padding и margin внутри flex элемента? Заранее извиняюсь за мои навыки в пеинте

Answer (score 0, accepted):

padding и margin для flex элементов устанавливаются также как и для блочных элементов. Здесь главное правило заключается в том, что все элементы выстраиваются в одну строку и, даже если они не помещаются в контейнер, они выходят за его пределы.
Элементы в контейнере по главной оси выравниваются с помощью свойства `justify-content`, вдоль поперечной оси - с помощью `align-items` (не путать с `align-content`, которое выравнивает строки относительно flex-контейнера).